# Clearing initial parameters set by Incenteev ParameterHandler

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I was just handed an existing PHP project that uses the [Incenteev ParamemeterHandler package](https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler) and I just ran `composer install` that asked me a bunch of questions.

It seems it was wrong to accept the default for some of them, and since re-running the command did not ask me again, I thought I needed to edit `app/config/parameters.yml` myself to fix this. Turns out, the next time I ran `composer install` it overwrote the new values!

This was unexpected, but I guess the previous values are stored somewhere and re-used to build that file. Now, I wonder how I can "clear" those values and/or fix up my wrong answer? I tried grepping for the field (`image_upload_dir` in my case), but that only had hits on other yml files, so I have no idea where it hides my cached responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even for a non-PHP programmer the source code for `ParameterHandler` is dead simple to read - the main bulk done by [160 lines of very readable PHP](https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler/blob/master/Processor.php). I found my answer there: it uses a template file called `app/config/parameters.yml.dist` (the `dist` extension is key) for default values.

If there already is a `parameters.yml` file there it will only prompt you for values that are not present. Meaning the answer to my question is simply to delete the file. I could also delete the fields I want to be prompted to answer again, but that is much less intuitive than simply hand-editing the file.

The reason I thought my values were overwritten was that the `dist` file had a line with this content `image_upload_dir: ~`. I read this to mean that the value was the home directory, the usual meaning of the tilde character on unices. I was therefore surprised when I saw the generated file having a corresponding line of `image_upload_dir: null`. Turns out I was not familiar with basic YAML: the tilde character, `~`, means `nil` or "empty", which means a `null` is perfectly in line with that.